# My code repeats the same function a lot but it has many different variables, is there a way to make it shorter?

Tags: python

My code simply tells me how much XP you would get depending on two variables. The conditions have been repeated multiple times.

**The condition for XP is basically:**
If alone, xp gives 4 times.
If in a pair, xp is 3 times.
If in a trio, xp is 2 times,
If 4 players, xp is 1.5x.
If 5 players, xp is the same.

These are the EXP gains per level:

```
LVL 1 = 5
LVL 2 = 7
LVL 3 = 8
LVL 4= 10
LVL 5= 13
LVL 6 = 16
LVL 7 = 17
LVL 8 = 21
LVL 9 = 26
LVL 10 = 30
LVL 11 = 36
LVL 12 = 42
LVL 13 = 45
LVL 14 = 48
LVL 15 = 50
LVL 16 = 53
LVL 17 = 54
LVL 18 = 57
LVL 19 = 61
LVL 20 = 75
```

Code:

```
x = int(input("How many people are you?"))
y = int(input("What Level is the player?"))

if y == 4:
    if x == 1:
        print("40 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("30 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("20 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("15 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("10 XP each.")

if y == 4:
    if x == 1:
        print("40 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("30 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("20 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("15 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("10 XP each.")

if y == 5:
    if x == 1:
        print("52 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("39 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("26 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("20 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("13 XP each.")

if y == 6:
    if x == 1:
        print("64 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("48 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("32 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("24 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("16 XP each.")

if y == 7:
    if x == 1:
        print("72 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("51 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("34 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("25 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("17 XP each.")
    
if y == 8:
    if x == 1:
        print("84 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("63 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("42 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("31 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("21 XP each.")

if y == 9:
    if x == 1:
        print("104 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("78 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("52 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("39 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("26 XP each.")

if y == 10:
    if x == 1:
        print("120 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("90 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("60 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("45 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("30 XP each.")

if y == 11:
    if x == 1:
        print("144 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("108 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("72 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("54 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("36 XP each.")

if y == 12:
    if x == 1:
        print("168 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("126 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("84 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("63 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("42 XP each.")

if y == 13:
    if x == 1:
        print("180 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("135 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("90 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("68 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("45 XP each.")

if y == 14:
    if x == 1:
        print("192 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("144 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("96 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("72 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("48 XP each.")

if y == 15:
    if x == 1:
        print("200 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("150 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("100 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("75 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("50 XP each.")

if y == 16:
    if x == 1:
        print("212 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("159 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("106 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("80 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("53 XP each.")

if y == 17:
    if x == 1:
        print("216 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("162 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("108 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("81 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("54 XP each.")

if y == 18:
    if x == 1:
        print("228 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("171 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("114 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("86 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("57 XP each.")

if y == 19:
    if x == 1:
        print("244 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("183 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("122 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("91.5 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("61 XP each.")

if y == 20:
    if x == 1:
        print("300 XP")
    if x == 2:
        print("225 XP each.")
    if x == 3:
        print("150 XP each.")
    if x == 4:
        print("112 XP each")
    if x == 5:
        print("75 XP each.")
```

Comment: It looks like your party XP multipliers are based on some simple mathematical rules. Do you know that Python can *do* math? You don't have to hardcode the results of `7 * 5` or `16 * 2` or all of that; you can have Python multiply numbers for you.

Comment: Look into https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions All conditions can be put in a function of x,y which uses a mapping of y to experience. For mapping see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code.

```
level_xp = {
    1 : 5,
    2 : 7,
    3 : 8,
    4: 10,
    5: 13,
    6 : 16,
    7 : 17,
    8 : 21,
    9 : 26,
    10 : 30,
    11 : 36,
    12 : 42,
    13 : 45,
    14 : 48,
    15 : 50,
    16 : 53,
    17 : 54,
    18 : 57,
    19 : 61,
    20 : 75
}

size_xp = {
    1: 4,
    2: 3,
    3: 2,
    4: 1.5,
    5: 1
}

party_size = int(input("How many people are you?"))
player_level = int(input("What Level is the player?"))

XP = size_xp[party_size] * level_xp[player_level]
if party_size == 1:
    print("%d XP" % XP)
else:
    print("%d XP each." % XP)
```

What I did was use a Python `dictionary` to map the level and size values to the amount of XP they represent. After figuring out how much XP each value is worth, I simply multiplied them. I still did use one if statement though because your code used the word "each" at the end of the sentence if there were multiple people.

Answer (score 0):

```
level_xp = [5,7,8,10,13,16,17,21,26,30,36,42,45,48,50,53,54,57,61,75]
p_multi = [4,3,2,1.5,1]

x = int(input("How many players?"))
y = int(input('Level of player'))

print(f"{level_xp[y-1]*p_multi[x-1]} XP")
```

Use Levels and Multipliers as lists, then reference them for an easier time, also now when u want to add new levels or edit multipliers, you don't have to change every single if statement..

Comment: what exactly does this line do?

print(f"{level_xp[y-1]*p_multi[x-1]} XP")